# sed replace text with equal sign =

Tags: sed, replace

I have lines of text that starts with this. (the dots at the back just represent some other dates in text and are not important).

```
2nd Monday,2019-01-14,2019-02-11,......
2nd Tuesday,2019-01-08,2019-02-12,......
```

What I want to do is to be able to replace part of the string of each line with an equal sign using sed. Something like this. Note I only want to replace the first comma `,`, ie. making it looks like this `2nd Monday=2019-01-14,2019-02-11,...`

```
sed -i '' '/,2019/=2019/' file
```

But my terminal is giving me this error.

```
sed: 1: "/,2019/=/": extra characters at the end of = command
```

Seeing that it is a command, I then tried to escape it with a backslash `\`.

```
sed -i '' '/,2019/\=2019/' file
```

But this gives this error.

```
sed: 1: "/,2019/\=/": invalid command code \
```

It works if the search string part contains an equal sign `=`, but apparently not when the equal sign is in the sed replacement string part.

I searched for probably 30 minutes now, but can't find anything on Google. Appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: You're missing the s.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
sed 's/,/=/1' filename
```

It replaces the first "," of each line with "=" sign.